# Gnuradio software source block

Tags: gnuradio

I'm currently trying to do some real-time signal-processing and I would like to use "gnuradio". I will be processing multiple channels of EEG which come in trough a custom interface (namely "Lab Streaming Layer"; LSL) in python. 
Now my question is if there is an existing block already where you can kind of "push" samples into the signal-processing-graph during run-time? The only blocks I've found so far offer support for audio hardware, TCP-streams and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write your own block; that can be done in Python or C++, whatever is better for your case.

The [GNU Radio Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials) (you should really read them in order from 1 to 5, at least) do explain how to do that.

Because we all know that people are lazy at reading, here's a rough preview of what you'll learn:

1. make a new Out-of-tree module: `gr_modtool newmod sensorinterface`, change into the newly generated directory: `cd gr-sensorinterface`
2. add a new source block: `gr_modtool add eeg_sensor_source`; the block type you'll want is "source"; you will be asked to fill in some block details.
3. edit the generated source file (in `lib/` or `python/`, depending on which language you chose:

   1. add a proper io signature: your output will probably have the size of `float`
   2. edit the central `work` function; add code to get new samples, and copy those to the `output_items` buffer.

The guided tutorials are really nice!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I can be sure that there is no block for this I will go trough the rest of the tutorial :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible method is to write your own GNU Radio block, but there are several options for getting data into a flow graph without using any custom blocks. (Naming from the Python perspective.)

- `gnuradio.blocks.message_source`, which takes data from a `gnuradio.gr.msg_queue`.
- You can use a `gnuradio.blocks.file_descriptor_source` where the file descriptor is one end of a pipe.